# Trying to read the date from API on JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to get the holidays from the city I live, but every time that I tried to specify the field, I got the undefined statement.

```js
function getHolidays() {
    fetch('https://api.calendario.com.br/?json=true&ano=2020&ibge=3550308&token=bHVjYXNsdm81M0BnbWFpbC5jb20maGFzaD03ODE3NDM2MA')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(function (verify) {
            const test = verify
            console.log(test.date)
        })
}

console.log(getHolidays())
```

Comment: Did you checked the api response? Its an array, you should iterate over it.

Comment: Thank you, I figure out that it was in an array either, but how could i iterate over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that API is returning an array of objects. You can iterate the array using the [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), for instance:

```
const dates = verify.map(item => item.date);
```

Also, is important to mention that fetch is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If you want to access its result outside the `getHolidays` function, you must handle it.

```
function getHolidays() {
    return fetch('https://api.calendario.com.br/?json=true&ano=2020&ibge=3550308&token=bHVjYXNsdm81M0BnbWFpbC5jb20maGFzaD03ODE3NDM2MA')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(function (verify) {
            return verify.map(item => item.date)
        })
}

getHolidays().then(function (dates) {
  console.log(dates);
});
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Tércio, deu certo! (Thank you Tércio, It worked for me.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're returning before the promise object has been fulfilled. If you were to replace the first "return" for example with another console log then you might get a pending result

Answer (score 0):

As @EliasSoares mentioned, you are trying to access an object property on an array.. You'll need to index into a certain object to grab that property (the property being `date`).

Something like this should help:

```js
function getHolidays() {
  fetch(
      "https://api.calendario.com.br/?json=true&ano=2020&ibge=3550308&token=bHVjYXNsdm81M0BnbWFpbC5jb20maGFzaD03ODE3NDM2MA"
    )
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log({ holidays: data });
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = `<h1>Results:</h1>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`;
    });
}

getHolidays()
```

```html
Open your console
<pre id="results" />
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, but I used Tércio's answer to solve it.

Comment: @user13702769 no problem! Glad you were able to find a resolution :)